# What options to I have to pass a value between two asp.net pages

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to know what the best practice is for passing values (sometimes multiple values) between two asp.net pages

In the past I have used query strings to pass a value in asp like this:

```
href='<%# Eval("TestID","../Net/TestPage.aspx?TestID={0}") %>'><%#Eval("Title")%> </a>
```

I assume you can do this in the code behind but I do not know the best way.

I also assume it is possible to pass more than one value.

Could someone provide me with a VB snippet which would give me an idea of how to go about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have many options for passing data and all of them can pass multiple values between pages.

You can use the [Request.Form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form.aspx) collection to capture values that have been submitted from an HTML form with the POST verb (i.e. " method="POST">).

The code looks something like:

```
Dim formvalue As String
formValue = Request.Form("FormField1")
```

You can also use parameters in a URL [query string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx) (much like you example):

```
Dim queryStringValue As String
queryStringValue = Request.QueryString("QueryStringValue1")
```

You can set a [cookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.cookies.aspx) (it's lifetime will depend on the Expiry property value that you set):

Setting a cookie (note: you use the HttpResponse object here. The user's browser stores the cookie when it receives the Set-Cookie HTTP header value from the response to a request)

```
Response.Cookies("CookieValue") = "My Cookie Data"
Response.Cookies("CookieValue").Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1) ' optional, expires tomorrow
```

Retrieving a cookie value (we use the HttpRequest object here):

```
Dim cookieValue As String
cookieValue = Request.Cookies("CookieValue")
```

You can use the HttpSessionState object (accessible via the [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.session.aspx) property of a page). To set a session variable:

```
Session["SessionValue"] = "My Session Value"
```

To retrieve a session value:

```
Dim sessionValue As String
sessionValue = Session["SessionValue"]
```

There's another way to pass page state between pages using `Page.Transfer` (see [How to: Pass Values Between ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw(VS.80).aspx)), but I'd try and get comfortable with the above before looking into that.

---

As far as best practices go it really depends on what data you're passing.

- **Don't** pass sensitive data via URLs (query strings), forms or cookies. These can intercepted in various ways
- Pass sensitive data using a server-side store (like session state or a database) but consider how to keep the session ID safe.
- **Never** trust data from outside your application (data that users have entered via a form, information read from a database, etc.). Always encode this information before displaying it again in your pages. This prevents against [Cross-Site Scripting (a.k.a XSS) attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).
- Don't use sequential IDs in query strings where you're passing user-specific identifiers between pages. Say you create an Orders.aspx page that lists all orders for a customer. You pass in a CustID parameter via a query string: Orders.aspx?CustID=123. It's easy for someone to change the URL to Orders.aspx?CustID=124 and view information they shouldn't. You can get around this by doing a check that the current user is allowed to see the information, you can use an identfier that can't be easily guessed (commonly a GUID) or pass the information on the server-side.

Answer (score 3):

It would help you to check out the following links:

a. [Cross page postbacks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx)

b. [How to pass values between ASP.NET pages (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw.aspx)

c. [Another article by Steve C. Orr on Passing values](http://steveorr.net/faq/PassValues.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a session, cookies, the query string, hidden form fields in a post request.

Comment: Can you use hidden form fields for an asp.net cross-page request?

Comment: @Andomar: You can use the Page.PreviousPage.FindControl("hiddenControl") method to access the hidden field. Reference: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CrossPagePosting.aspx